# Auto Update every picture in a PowerPoint Slideshow

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a very large and complex PowerPoint with a full size image as the background for every individual slide.  I have a directory full of these background pictures, which are all JPEG's.  Sometimes I change these photographs, which are made with Photoshop, and when I change them, I save them over the original JPEG in the same directory.

I then have to update them in the PowerPoint.  The manual functios to do this is to right-click the photograph, and click replace photo, then pick the new JPEG from the file menu.  I want to write a macro in Visual Basic that will go through the entire slideshow, and reload the graphic from the updated JPEGs, without me having to do it manually.  I don't know if it is possible, because I don't know if PowerPoint actually remembers the path and filename of each picture that it places.

Is there a picture property which contains the path and filename that was used to paste the picture in the first place?  If there is, I could find that property, query it, and use that as the path to reload and thereby update the picture recursively all the way through slide by slide.

Would this be possible?

Comment: This should be handier nowadays with manual and automatic update of every picture in the presentation:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/update-linked-images-in-powerpoint-version-1908/dd1ccbaa-a431-402c-8263-90c50c6896ee

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a picture property which contains the path and filename that was used to paste the picture in the first place?

Not that I'm aware of, but you can create your own, using the Tags property:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744290(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744290%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

You will have to assign a custom tag for each slide, like:

```
Sub AssignTag()
    Dim sld as Slide
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    sld.Tags.Add "img_location", "C:\files\image1.JPG"

End Sub
```

Once the slide's `Tags` have been configured, then you can do something like this to update from that location:

```
Sub UpdateJPGs()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim path As String

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        path = sld.Tags("img_location")
        If Not path = vbNullString Then
            On Error Resume Next
            sld.Background.Fill.UserPicture path
            If Err Then
                MsgBox "Unable to update slide #" & sld.SlideNumber
                Err.Clear
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That is pretty ingenious, I had no idea you could add your own tags,  Thanks a lot David.

Comment: You can also add CustomXML to each slide, which I would recommend if you needed to store a *lot* of information about each slide. But it is more difficult to implement, so the simple "Tags" should work for this purpose.  Cheers, and if this solves the problem do mark the answer as "Accepted"

Comment: I guess I first will have to go through the whole presentation and assign all the background JPEG paths, because they will be different for every slide, right?  But after that I can just run the UpdateJPGS subroutine and it should do it all.

Comment: Yes, once they are initially assigned, you should be able to run the UpdateJPGs subroutine to update all of them.

Comment: CustomXML has another drawback: it won't survive any conversion from XML to the earlier binary formats. And fwiw, I tested attaching huge amounts of data as tags way back in '97 and found that a megabyte of tag data caused no problems other than increasing the file size.  In that case, it's better to store lots of data per tag/fewer tags than to store lots of little bits of data in lots of tags.

Comment: It works.  Now what if I want to have the routine change the content of an inserted picture named "Picture 1" in each slide instead of the background?

Comment: You can refer to the picture shape like : `sld.Shapes("Picture 3").Fill.UserPicture = "c:\location\imagefile.jpg"` where `sld` is an object variable representing a specific slide in the presentation.  Very similar to example above.  Shapes can also have `Tags`, so it would be a very similar implementation.

Comment: VB rejects the '.UserPicture = ' syntax.  "Argument not optional"  Why would that be?

Comment: Get rid of the `=` in that statement